# Выполнение цикла в нескольких потоках

Tags: java

Мне нужно посчитать сумму арифметической прогрессии с помощью цикла в нескольких потоках
Вот исходный код(создаю 32 потока). Как мне разбить цикл на всех них? Допустим хочу посчитать сумму от 0 до 1 000 000 000 с шагом в 3, чтобы каждый поток выполнял отдельную часть

```
 public class MainClass {
 public static void main(String arg[]) throws IllegalArgumentException {  
 Refresh() ;
}
   static class MyThread1 extends Thread {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   }

}

public static void Refresh(){

    //create 32 Thread using for loop
    for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
        // Create Thread class
        MyThread1 temp = new MyThread1();
        temp.start();
        try {
            temp.join(10);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: передайте какие-то параметры в конструктор потока. А вообще подобная задача формулой решается...

Comment: посмотрите здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/948455/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-java-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f/948613#948613